# IE 11 & F12 - Emulation showing only 2 options at Document Mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

Anyone has an idea why my IE11 is showing only 2 options in the document mode?

[image]

Comment: Are you running all of the latest updates to IE? I see all of the modes in the IE11's F12 Developer tools.

Comment: Yes, last version (flag to auto update enabled)

Comment: This looks like the behavior from the beta.  What version of IE11 does Help/About say you have?

Comment: @Shady: The "Install new versions automatically" checkbox has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

By zooming the page I saw the site was https://suporte.0800net.com.br/ . If you look at the network trace you will see that it is sending not one, but two headers forcing IE into IE5 mode. There is no doctype on the page so it is in Quirks mode by default. The console has a warning message about it. The first header isn't even correct but I guess IE does *something* with it.

You can override the settings in the page using a meta tag.

[image: Network trace]
[image: Console output]

Comment: thx for your reply. Just to clarify, I have several coworkers with IE 11 that access the same website and in the document mode show ao possible modes, in case EDGE, 1, 9,8,7 and 5.